# Set a default Ruby version for a specific directory (RVM)

Tags: ruby, macos, unix, directory, rvm

How can I use RVM to set a default ruby version for a certain directory? So that every time I `cd` into that directory, it switches to my preferred version of Ruby.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way is to use a `Gemfile` and set the ruby version in it. like so:

```
ruby '2.2.0'
```

then when you enter the directory you will see the following message from `rvm`

```
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/danmanstx/rails_projects/app/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.
```

Answer (score 14):

Directly from the [RVM documentation](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects):

> RVM supports multiple files allowing to configure a project for automated ruby switching. In any case make sure to add those files to your version control systems as it is part of the project configuration.
>
> Listed in order of precedence:
>
> - .rvmrc - shell script allowing full customization of the environment,
> - .versions.conf - key=value configuration file
> - .ruby-version - single line ruby-version only
> - Gemfile" - comment: #ruby=1.9.3 and directive: ruby "1.9.3"

Comment: This is the most complete answer posted so far.

Comment: I'd also note that although it's third on the list, I think the `.ruby-version` is the most generally preferred method, unless you have a specific need for a feature of one of the others.

Answer (score 5):

Create a `.ruby-version` file in that directory with your version information. To set version as 2.1.2 for a directory, create the file with only "2.1.2" as the content.

```
$ cat .ruby-version
2.1.2
```

Answer (score 2):

in rails 6 you only have to change what's inside of .ruby-version in your app folder

Comment: I upgraded the ruby version in my Gemfile (2.5.2 => 2.7.2) but the one in .ruby-version did not change. Do I have to change it manually ?

Answer (score 1):

Or simply use `rvm --ruby-version ruby_version@gemset --create` , --create here will create the gemset if it is not present already. If you don't need to specify a gemset, but instead use the default gemset. leave out `@gemset --create`. `ruby_version` for example `2.0.0`.